# Delete answer option in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ipad

I've just answered a question wrongly, but unlike on the regular site, there's no option to delete my incorrect answer.

Although fairly minor, it would save me having to find a computer or use safari (which is far more fiddly)